# facebook click like event fb event subscribe not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here is my code. At the end you will see a javascript call to `FB.Event.subscribe`. In my console it says **FB not defined**. What can I do to get this javascript to capture my like click.

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Your Website Title</title>
        <!-- You can use open graph tags to customize link previews.
        Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
      <meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />
      <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
      <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
      <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
      <meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />
    </head>
    <body>

      <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

      <!-- Your like button code -->
      <div class="fb-like"
        data-href="xxx.com"
        data-layout="standard"
        data-action="like"
        data-show-faces="true">
      </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
        alert('clicked');      
    }); 
    </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

**UPDATE**

here is my update (still not working)

```
      <script>

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId            : 'xxxxxx',
          autoLogAppEvents : true,
          xfbml            : true,
          version          : 'v2.9'
        });
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
      };


    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;   
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

      <!-- Your like button code -->
      <div class="fb-like"
        data-href="www.xxx.com"
        data-layout="standard"
        data-action="like"
        data-show-faces="true">
      </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
        alert('clicked');
    });
    </script>
```

**NEWEST UPDATE**

I put the subscribe code inside the async call and still no work.

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Your Website Title</title>
        <!-- You can use open graph tags to customize link previews.
        Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
      <meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />
      <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
      <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
      <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
      <meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />
    </head>
    <body>

      <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId            : 'xxxx',
          autoLogAppEvents : true,
          xfbml            : true,
          version          : 'v2.9'
        });
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
        FB.AppEvents.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) { 
          alert('clicked');
        });

       // also tried:
       FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) { 
          alert('clicked');
        });
      };


    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;   
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

      <!-- Your like button code -->
      <div class="fb-like"
        data-href="www.xxx.com"
        data-layout="standard"
        data-action="like"
        data-show-faces="true"
        >
      </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

** HERE IS THE DIV HTML CODE FACEBOOK GAVE ME, WHICH I RECREATED IN JAVASCRIPT**

```
var elm=newElement("div",this.canvas,"",0,"");
 elm.className="fb-like";
 elm.dataset.href="www.XXX.com";
 elm.dataset.layout="standard";
 elm.dataset.action="like";
 elm.dataset.showFaces=false;
 elm.style.marginTop="75px";
 elm.style.marginLeft="25px";
 console.log(elm);
```

Comment: Subscribe inside the fbAsyncInit event. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

Comment: @CBroe look at updates. it looks like the fb library is not being loaded.

Comment: It is in the process of loading, but that happens asynchronously. That’s why they give you this event, so that you can do whatever requires the SDK to be loaded and initialized already in there. (Remove `xfbml=1&version=v2.9` from the script address, because that triggers initialization implicitly already, and can circumvent correct calling of the event handler.)

Comment: @CBroe ok i removed the extra code. its still not working. how do i incorporate the click event into this code?

Comment: _"Subscribe **inside** the fbAsyncInit event"_

Comment: @CBroe its requiring me to click the like twice, once before the login, and once after the login, for the on click event to fire. besides that its working well.

Comment: Well you can not like a page via the button before you login to Facebook, so that does not sound unusual.

Comment: @CBroe That makes sense. One final question - i cannot see the page as liked on my facebook dashboard. is it being stored somewhere, like within the app/page itself instead of on the users dashboard?

Comment: @CBroe Is that something different - following? arent they following once they click like?

Comment: @CBroe sorry for separating my comments please read both of them above thanks!

Comment: Like is like, and follow is follow. Usually following is active when a user likes a page, but they can turn it of afterwards. And I think you can follow without liking a page as well. // As long as it shows up in your activity log, everything went fine. Not everything is shown on the user profile.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry for the excessive comments. Your help is very appreciative. My only remaining issue is I'd like for the user to follow our page AND ALSO when i click on liked pages i do not see our site. How do I incorporate the following into my code? I added ABOVE the html code FACEBOOK provided me as well.

Comment: @CBroe I was able to get following in place. However, the event is no longer working as edge.create. I cannot locate the new event code online?

Comment: @CBroe see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399130/facebook-follow-api-subscription-event-code-not-edg