# facebook follow and like api subscription event code (edge.create not working)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've implemented liking a website url along with attaching the edge.create event to it.  **I implemented the follow button but did not get the edge.create to function when clicking to follow button.** Also, I cannot figure out how to **like a specific facebook page and as well get the edge.create event to subscribe.**

I have the following code for when a user performs a **LIKE** on our website (not the facebook page):

**This code works well**

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId            : 'xxxxxx',
          autoLogAppEvents : true,
          xfbml            : true,
          version          : 'v2.9'
        });
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
          alert(1);
         });
      };

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

      <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/fbpage" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true"/>
    }
```

Here is my code for **following a facebook page** , which works but **does not fire the edge.create code**

```
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId            : 'xxxxx',
          autoLogAppEvents : true,
          xfbml            : true,
          version          : 'v2.9'
        });
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
          alert(1);
        });    
      };

     (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

      <div class="fb-follow" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/fbpage" data-layout="standard" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true"/>
```

As you can see, **I need help getting the edge.create to function with clicking follow button** and if possible a way to like a specific facebook page along with the edge.create event code.

Comment: No there is no way. Why do you want to know when they follow or like?

Comment: @WizKid That is incorrect. The above code provides me access to after the user clicks like so i can do my backend work. It uses the event code `edge.create`. I'm looking for something similar with following.

Comment: I am correct. There is no way for following. And you didn't answer why you need to know

Comment: I need to perform some backend javascript work after the user clicks the follow link, including a redirection (as what i did above you can see the alert this is where it currently goes). Sorry you said something about like and i already have that implemented so I assumed there would be something similar with following

Comment: Like gating is not allowed. You are not allowed to do different things depending if the user liked or not

Comment: @WizKid I dont think were talking about the same thing. I'm looking at this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.9 why can i do this with likes but not follows? Im not 'gating' anything all im looking to do is perform code AFTER they hit the follow button on my website just like i implemented above with like button.

Comment: I'm saying what you are doing with likes are not allowed. You are not allowed to do something different just because they liked.

Comment: Theres absolutely nothing wrong with what I'm doing. This is called event subscriptions in Facebook. I can hook into the edge.create event which gets fired after the like is executed. Im doing everything de facto with facdebooks requirements.

Comment: So you read https://developers.facebook.com/policy ?

Comment: @WizKid What part of the policy are you referring to?

Comment: Im out right now ill look later at it

Comment: I am dealing with the same issue. Like button can be subscribed to using `edge.create` which fires when someone likes the page using a Like button. There is no apparent way to do the same with the follow button.